# What is the definable functor associated to an algebraic scheme (model theory of valued fields)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, model-theory, valuation-theory, berkovich-geometry

I have a very basic question regarding algebraic model theory. I am trying to read [*Espaces de Berkovich, polytopes, squelettes et théorie des modèles*](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793744212500077) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3020334)) by Antoine Ducros. The relevant section is Section 0.31. Let me give the setup: Let $K$ be a valued field and let $\mathscr{C}_K$ be the category of non-trivially valued, algebraically closed field extensions of $K$. We write $\mathscr{L}_\mathrm{val}$ for the language of valued fields, having three sorts (the valued field, its residue field and the value group).

Let $\mathscr{S}$ be a product of sorts. For each model of the theory of non-trivially valued, algebraically closed field extensions of $K$, i.e. for each $F \in \mathscr{C}_K$, we can then make sense of $\mathscr{S}(F)$, and this gives a functor $\mathscr{S} \colon \mathscr{C}_K \to \mathrm{Set}$. If $\Phi(x)$ is a formula of $\mathscr{L}_\mathrm{val}$ (with parameters in $K$), whose free variables $x$ live in $\mathscr{S}$, then the subfunctor of $\mathscr{S}$ mapping $F$ to $\{x \in \mathscr{S}(F) \mid \Phi(x)\}$ is called a *definable subfunctor* of $\mathscr{S}$.

In general, an abstract functor from $\mathscr{C}_K$ to $\mathrm{Set}$ is called *definable* if it is isomorphic to a definable subfunctor of some product of sorts.

Now it is claimed that a scheme of finite type $\mathscr{X}$ over $K$ gives rise to a definable functor on $\mathscr{C}_K$. I don't understand why this is true. If $\mathscr{X}$ is affine, then I believe that the associated functor should simply be the “functor of points”. Namely, if $\mathscr{X}$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(K[T_1, \dots, T_n] / \langle f_1, \dots, f_r\rangle)$, then its associated functor is isomorphic to the definable subfunctor of $F \mapsto F^n$, given by the equations $f_i$. I have no idea, what is meant in the non-affine case. I would be very glad about some clarification. Also, if some of my writing above hints at some misunderstanding on my side, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows by elimination of imaginaries in algebraically closed fields. Given a finite affine cover of your scheme, one obtains a functor to Set by gluing the affine charts. This is indeed not definable, but a quotient of a definable set by a definable equivalence relation. Elimination of imaginaries tells you precisely that such a quotient is in definable bijection with a definable set. You can find the details in Chapter 4 ([A. Pillay, Model theory of algebraically closed fields](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-68521-0_4)) of the following book:

*Bouscaren, Elisabeth*, Introduction to model theory, Bouscaren, Elisabeth (ed.), [Model theory and algebraic geometry](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-68521-0). An introduction to E. Hrushovski’s proof of the geometric Mordell-Lang conjecture. Berlin: Springer. Lect. Notes Math. 1696, 1-18 (1998). [ZBL0925.03160](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0925.03160).

Chapters [1](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-68521-0_1) and [2](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-68521-0_2) also contain an introduction to general model theoretic concepts including elimination of imaginaries (Chapter 2).

Comment: I edited in links to the book and the individual chapters.  Since you later cite Chapter 1 separately, I think you didn't mean your reference and corresponding ZBL link to refer only to the first chapter, but rather to the whole book.  That's [ZBL0920.03046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0920.03046).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If I understand “gluing affine charts” correctly, then you are saying that also for general $\mathscr{X}$, the associated functor is the functor of points, sending $F$ to $\mathscr{X}(F) = \mathrm{Hom}_K(\mathrm{Spec}(F), \mathscr{X})$, right? Could you maybe indicate for some simple non-affine scheme like $\mathbf{P}^1_K$, how the bijection that you get to a definable functor would look like?

Comment: By the way, thank you for the hints to the literature, I will definitely have a look at it.

Comment: Indeed, the functor is isomorphic to the functor of points. In the case of $\mathbf{P}_K^n$, the functor of points is isomorphic to the functor sending $F$ to the set of $n$-dimensional subspaces of $F^{n+1}$. The usual equivalence relation on $F^{n+1}$ given by $(x_0,\ldots, x_n)\sim(y_0,\ldots,y_n)$ if and only if there is $\lambda\in F^*$ such that $\lambda x_i=y_i$ for each $i\in \{0,\ldots,n\}$ is the corresponding definable equivalence relation.

Comment: In the special case of $\mathbf{P}_K^1$, you can identify such a quotient with the definable functor which sends $F$ to the (definable) set $\{(x,y)\in F^2 : y=1\} \cup \{(1,0)\}$. For $\mathbf{P}_K^n(F)$ you can cook up a similar description. For general schemes of finite type, the fact that you can find this definable (set) functor is precisely the content of elimination of imaginaries.

Comment: Note that the choice is made up to definable bijection (or up to isomorphism of definable functors in your terminology). Indeed, I could also define the functor for $\mathbf{P}_K^1$ as sending $F$ to $\{(x,y) \in F^2 : y=1\}\cup\{(2,0)\}$. In any case, the existence of such a functor is granted by elimination of imaginaries.

Comment: @Cubikova I see. So this is really only an abstract existence statement “there exists some isomorphism onto a definable functor”, and this isomorphism is in no way canonical or natural, not even after the choice of an affine covering. Thank you for your help.